# Strange character when importing '.csv' file in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

So I'm trying to use SSIS to import a '.csv' file into SQL Server. The import works fine but the issue I'm having is that when I import the file, each field has the character � appended.

I've been trying all morning to fix this through SSIS but I'm not having any luck. What I have just noticed is that when I open the '.csv' file and go to Save As it shows up as Unicode Text rather than an actual csv. If I save it as a csv and then run that through all the fields come through fine without the � character.

So I have a fix of sorts but it requires me manually opening and re-saving the files, which I can't have as I need the process to be able to run automatically. I had the thought of converting the file automatically using a C# script task but I don't know how to do that, is anybody able to assist? Or is there a better way to do it that I don't know of?

Thank you.

Comment: so to clearify: the problem is the encoding of your csv file, which is not matching the expected encoding in SSIS? Then you could of course use C# - in .NET there is the Encoding Class which provides you with many encodings (from the ?-character i would say you need it as ASCII)

Comment: I think it is the encoding yes, I'm not 100% sure as when I open my working version and the original version of the file in Notepad++ they appear identical. What I'm going off is when I open the original file in Excel and go to Save As it says unicode text, not csv.

If there is an Encoding Class that'd be perfect for what I need, I'll see if I can look it up thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple Powershell script to change the encoding:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem *.csv) {
    Get-Content $file.name | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 "UTF8_$($file.name)"
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell so I may have missed something obvious but this didn't seem to work when I ran it? The fields still come through with the weird characters

Comment: Create a new text file, add the content above to it. Save as *.ps1. Then open a powershell window, cd to the folder where you have the *.csv files and then run the script .\myscript.ps1. It should generate new files with UTF8_ prefix. (PS: I edited the script)