# Change CSV format to CSV acceptable by powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv, export-csv

I have CSV file in below format, when I am editing it in notepad I see following content: please see A - code area

I need something like below, I always have this format when using export-csv from powershell. please see B - code area

I need to use this CSV file in powershell script. I was trying to convert it in excell, and try to use this powershell command:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\PS\FileIN.csv | Export-Csv -Path FileOUT.csv -NoTypeInformation UTF8
```

.I know that I can do it in Notepad++, but I dont want to perform this task manually. Is there any method I can use to convert this CSV file to required format?

```
# A - Now I see this format
COL1;COL2;COL3;COL4
value1;value2;value3;value4
value5;value6;value7;value8

# B - I need this format"
"COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4"
"value1","value2","value3","value4"
"value5","value6","value7","value8"
```

Comment: Try: `Import-CSV -Delimiter ';' -Path C:\PS\FileIN.CSV | Export-CSV -Path FileOut.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Yes, it worked, but now in the output file I see values like "test ? text" instead "text - text", do You know what is the problem? I tried to use  in the export-csv command paratemers "-NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8", but I see in the output file --> "�"

Comment: Add `-Encoding UTF8` to your `Import-CSV` command: `Import-CSV -Delimiter ';' -Path C:\PS\FileIN.CSV -Encoding UTF8  | Export-CSV -Path FileOut.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: I added "-Encoding UTF8" at the end of the command, and now output looks fine, thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change delimiter in a csv from ; to ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645193/change-delimiter-in-a-csv-from-to) and [Strange character when importing '.csv' file in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283483/strange-character-when-importing-csv-file-in-ssis?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Suggested powershell command resolved the problem, additionally i added parameter: -encoded UTF8 at the end od the command.

Import-CSV -Delimiter ';' -Path C:\PS\FileIN.CSV -Encoding UTF8  | Export-CSV -Path FileOut.csv -NoTypeInformation -Enconing UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Add `-Encoding UTF8` to your `Import-CSV` command:

```
Import-CSV -Delimiter ';' -Path C:\PS\FileIN.CSV -Encoding UTF8 | Export-CSV -Path FileOut.csv -NoTypeInformation
```